# Reorder dataframe columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Is there a way to order columns in a Pandas dataframe from a txt-files:

```
pandas.DataFrame.read_table
```

For example from csv file, using:

```
pandas.DataFrame.to_csv
```

you can pass order columns in

```
columns
```

Or generally, Is there a way to re-order dataframe columns? Maybe using .ix module?

Comment: have you looked at DataFrame.sort?  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use indexing to reorder the columns. For example,

```
In [119]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(24).reshape(6,4), columns=list('ABCD'))

In [120]: df
Out[120]: 
    A   B   C   D
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
4  16  17  18  19
5  20  21  22  23

In [121]: df[list('CDAB')]
Out[121]: 
    C   D   A   B
0   2   3   0   1
1   6   7   4   5
2  10  11   8   9
3  14  15  12  13
4  18  19  16  17
5  22  23  20  21
```

So simply read in the data as usual using `pd.read_table`, and then reorder the columns using

```
df = df[['col1', 'col2', ...]]
```